# Array merge not merging one element

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

**Array 1** : `$gpsArr`

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
        )

    [store_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Out of the Blue - Powai
        )

    [store_logo] => Array
        (
            [0] => /Out-of-the-Blue-Powai.jpg
        )

    [deals_image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

**Array 2** : `$dataArr`

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87
            [1] => 88
            [2] => 99
            [3] => 100
        )

    [store_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => The Barking Deer Brewpub
            [1] => The Den
            [2] => Mini Punjab's Chinese Court
            [3] => Out of the Blue - Khar
        )

    [store_logo] => Array
        (
            [0] => /The-barking-deer-brewpub.png
            [1] => /the-den.png
            [2] => /Mini-Punjabs-Chinese-Court-Bandra.png
            [3] => /Out-of-the-Blue-Khar.jpg
        )

    [deals_image] => Array
        (
            [0] => the-barking-deer-brewpub-thumb297.jpg
            [1] => the-den-thumb297.jpg
            [2] => mini-punjub-chinese-court-thumb297.jpg
            [3] => out-of-the-blue-Khar-thumb297.jpg
        )

)
```

By merging above two array using following code :

```
$result = array_unique(array_merge($gpsArr,$dataArr), SORT_REGULAR);
```

return following result :

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87
            [1] => 88
            [2] => 99
            [3] => 100
        )

    [store_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => The Barking Deer Brewpub
            [1] => The Den
            [2] => Mini Punjab's Chinese Court
            [3] => Out of the Blue - Khar
        )

    [store_logo] => Array
        (
            [0] => /The-barking-deer-brewpub.png
            [1] => /the-den.png
            [2] => /Mini-Punjabs-Chinese-Court-Bandra.png
            [3] => /Out-of-the-Blue-Khar.jpg
        )

    [deals_image] => Array
        (
            [0] => the-barking-deer-brewpub-thumb297.jpg
            [1] => the-den-thumb297.jpg
            [2] => mini-punjub-chinese-court-thumb297.jpg
            [3] => out-of-the-blue-Khar-thumb297.jpg
        )

)
```

As you can see `store_id = 101` is not displayed after merging the array. Why this is happening? I think I done something silly thing but can you please tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array_merge` isn't recursive, it doesn't combine sub-arrays. It just takes an element from one array or the other.

Comment: @Barmar so what should I do to merge this two array ?

Comment: `array_merge_recursive`?

Comment: BTW, `array_merge` doesn't take an option like `SORT_REGULAR`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @u_mulder thanks! using `array_merge_recursive`, it worked :)

Comment: @Barmar that is for the `array_unique`, not the `array_merge`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_merge_recursive()`

Comment: done already dude you are late sorry.Solution provided by @u_mulder